# How to apply modular arithmatic in expression containing divisions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I find the modulo if the expression contains divisions. Like:

$$\frac{p^a-1}{p-1} \pmod{1000,000,007},$$

where $(p^a-1)$ is divisible by $p-1$ and p is a prime, but a may not be. How do I calculate the modulo ?

Comment: Hint: for any prime $\;p\;,\;\;a^p=a\pmod p\;$ ...

Comment: But here p may not be a prime. But a is a prime .

Comment: You do modular division.

Comment: If $p$ is not a prime necessarily, it would help to not write it as $p$.

Comment: Edited, What is modular division?

Comment: The primeness of $a$ and $p$ are irrelevant actually; what really matters is whether $\gcd(p-1, 1000000007) = 1$ or not.

Comment: @Hurkyl,what should I do if gcd(p-1,10000000007) is not 1 ? I am really weak in modular arithmatic.

Comment: Suppose you want to find $x / 3 \pmod {11}$.  First you find $b$ such that $3 \cdot b = 1 \pmod {11}$, in this case $b = 4$.  Then you have $x / 3 = x \cdot 4 \pmod {11}$, that's how you do modular division.  You basically find $a^{-1} = b \pmod p$ and convert $x / a$ to $x \cdot b$, but the inverse doesn't always exist.

Comment: If you look at the "related" section on the right, there are a few questions about modular inverses and modular division you can look at.

Comment: @TamimAdDari Are you trying to compute a value or are you trying to analyze an expression?

Comment: I am trying to compute the value in a computer program. But as a and p can be very large that won't fit in the memory so I have to follow some technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Compute $X = p^a \pmod {1000000007}$ using [Modular Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method).
  2) Compute $B = (p - 1)^{-1} \pmod{1000000007}$ using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
  3) Compute $(X - 1)B \pmod {1000000007}$ using [Modular Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_Arithmetic).

---

In your case, $B$ can be calculated easily because $1000000007$ [is a prime](http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php); more importantly, as long as $p - 1 \ne 1000000007$ then $\operatorname{GCD}(p - 1, 1000000007) = 1$.  If it wasn't, this would be a much harder (but not impossible) problem.

To use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, rewrite the formula for $B$:

$$B \equiv (p - 1)^{-1} \pmod {1000000007} $$
$$(p - 1)B = 1 \pmod {1000000007}$$
$$(p - 1)B - 1000000007n = 1$$

Solve for $n$ and $B$, although you only need $B$.